# why is this list: [[-0.23684 -2.54357006 1.06844643]] returned as None Type? see the code output

Tags: python, numpy, oop

when output commands (1.) as listed below were execute you can see there is a list output : [[0.1357893  0.13558951 0.13562417]], when type of this output is asked by command (5.) it is output as class <'None Type'>. so the question is why this non empty list is called as none type. you can see there is no error output.

Also can you confirm if the output (2.) is a list of arrays that's why it list type.

1.Network.feed forward ([1,5])

2.print(Network.weights)

3.print(Network.biases)

4.print(type(Network.weights))

5.print(type(Network. feed forward([1,5])))

6.print(length (Network.weights))

it gives an output as below mentioned

1.`[[0.1357893  0.13558951 0.13562417]]`

2.`[array([[ 1.17769878,  1.09506853],
       [ 1.13799858,  2.71622618],
       [-0.35448734,  1.75165491]]), array([[-1.56395246,  0.83951109, 
       -0.27785569]])]`
3.`[array([[0.02232141],
       [0.65477376],
       [0.19102921]]), array([[-0.85011921]])]`

4.`<class 'list'>`
why this output?`[[0.13618594 0.1355904  0.13578948]]`

5.`<class 'NoneType'>`

6.2

> Process finished with exit code 0

here is the relevant code:

```
import numpy as np

class Network(object):

    def __init__(self, sizes):
        """The list ``sizes`` contains the number of neurons in the
        respective layers of the network.  """
        self.num_layers = len(sizes)
        self.sizes = sizes
        self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                        for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

    def feedforward(self, a):
        """Return the output of the network if ``a`` is input."""
        for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
            a = np.dot(w, a)+b
        print(a)


Network = Network([2,3,1])
Network.feedforward([1,5])
print(Network.weights)
print(Network.biases)
print(type(Network.weights))
print(type(Network.feedforward([1,5])))
print(len(Network.weights))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Network.feedforward([1,5])` does not return anything.

You need to add a `return` statement at the end of your `feedforward` function, since `feedforward` edits the array you give it but returns `None`.

Comment: yes you are right, since feedforward here in this code is leading to a print command and not outputting any list. hence the type <none type>. thanks

Comment: but you haven't answered my second question"also can you confirm if the output (2.) is a list of arrays that's why it list type." because when running a simple function like a = [array([[ 3.330358  , -0.57814197],
                         [-0.62616523,  0.767423  ],
   [-1.00848966, -1.38796324]]), array([[ 1.49145462, -0.53954357,-0.38789326]])]
    print(type(a)) it results in a type error " Type Error: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not list"

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you clarify what your question is and add some more formatting?

Comment: output to print(Network.weights) is [array([[ 1.17769878,  1.09506853],
                                                                   [ 1.13799858,  2.71622618],
                                                                   [-0.35448734,  1.75165491]]), 
                                          array([[-1.56395246,  0.83951109, -0.27785569]])] what kind of output is that, it is not an numpy array for sure. and it can't be array since python doesn't have inbuilt array .

Comment: and if it is a simple list, why mention array at first place in the output

Comment: to be more precise, if array in python is not predefined/ inbuilt, how it can output an array or list of arrays? As you can see we have to import from array in python for creating arrays.